# Removing value from an array based on compare values from a HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have an array type String[]

```
myArray = [value1,value2,value3,..,valueX]
```

and a HashMap `Map<String, String>`

```
myHashMap = {field1=value2,value3, field2=value1,value2,value3, ..., fieldN=value1,value2}
```

My goal is to remove a value from `myArray` which doesn't exists in `myHashMap(field1)` compared to values from `myHashMap(field2)`. In an example above it will be `value1`.

Any tips how to tackle that? I have tried to do something like that:

1. To check if `field1` and `field2` keys exist in `myHashMap`
2. Irritate over values for key `field2`
3. In that loop irritate over values from key `field1`
4. Compare both values (and here I have got stuck as values may not be in an order)

PS.
I'm limited to Java 7

Comment: What is `Map` type looks like `Map<String,String>`?

Comment: @javaguy yes, it is `Map<String, String>` I will update my question with that

Comment: Are we talking about just two fields in the map here? Or does the map contain multiple fields `field1..fieldN`, which would make this a generic problem? Another question... Is it a `Map<String, String>` or a `Map<String, List<String>>`? (The latter makes more sense).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yes, it may contain multiple fields but always must to check if a value exists in `field1`

Comment: @JackTheKnife Good! (That makes this a much more interesting problem) What about the values of the map? Are they just strings, or a list of strings?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner only strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would create a set of all the values `value1..valueX` of the map that are mapped to fields `field2..fieldN` (I'm explicitly excluding values mapped to `field1`):

```
Set<String> nonField1Values = new HashSet<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myHashMap.entrySet()) {
    if (!entry.getKey().equals("field1")) {
        String currentValue = entry.getValue();
        List<String> values = Arrays.asList(currentValue.split(","));
        nonField1Values.addAll(values);
    }
}
```

The `nonField1Values` set contains all the values that are mapped to the fields of the map (without repeated elements, since it's a set), except for `field1`'s values.

Next, I'd get `field1`'s value and create a set from it:

```
Set<String> field1Values = 
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(myHashMap.get("field1").split(",")));
```

Following step is to get the difference between these two sets:

```
nonField1Values.removeAll(field1Values);
```

Now `nonField1Values` contains only the elements of `nonField1Values` that are not present in `field1Values`.

The final step is to create a set from your array and remove all the elements that are contained in the `nonField1Values` set:

```
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
result.removeAll(nonField1Values);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> f = Arrays.asList(myHashMap.get("field1").split(","));
List<String> s = Arrays.asList(myHashMap.get("field2").split(","));

List<String> result = s.stream().filter(v -> !f.contains(v))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
myArray.removeAll(result);
```

This is a straight-forward solution.

As pointed out by **flakes**, the for-loop is redundant in this case and it can be solved in terms of `removeAll`. Here is a Java 7 solution:

```
//this list is immutable (it's fine)
List<String> first = Arrays.asList(myHashMap.get("field1").split(","));
// we would need a mutable copy of the second one:
List<String> second = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myHashMap.get("field2").split(",")));

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
second.removeAll(first);
myList.removeAll(second);
// if you need the result back as array:
String[] result = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
```

Comment: That solution requires Java 8

Comment: You can just use removeAll instead of using a loop. `[a,b,c].removeAll([b,c]) = [a]`

Comment: @NestorSokil On the line `myArray.removeAll(result);` it says that `java cannot invoke removeall(list<string>) on the array type string[]`. I have tried to add `toArray` on `result` but it looks like is not the way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

How about the following? It's not the most elegant way. There may be better answers:

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(map.getOrDefault("field1", "").split(",")));
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(map.getOrDefault("field2", "").split(",")));
s2.removeAll(s1);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String str : myArray) {
    if(!s2.contains(str))
        list.add(str);
}

return list.toArray(new String[0]);
```